# Web Deploy Failing After Upgrade to VS 2012

Tags: webdeploy, visual-studio-2012

I have a project, for which the publish (web deploy) to localhost was working under VS 2010.  I made no changes to the project, other than opening it in VS 2012 RC.

The publish from VS 2012 RC failed when I attempted it, with message saying that the service does not exist, even though the site exists in IIS and can be posted to.

Now when I open the project in VS 2010 and attempt to publish, the publish fails with the same issue.  Other projects where I have not attempted a publish in VS 2012 RC still have working publish profiles.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, what have you done to correct it?  I have looked into all the usual issues as to why a publish might fail, but publishes of other projects to IIS as local host on the same machine are working, so I think that rules out any failing services.

Comment: perhaps something here is relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946340/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-task-failed

Comment: Nope not relevant to my issue, sorry.  This is the same IIS instance on the same machine, same sites.  The only difference is 2010 vs 2012RC.

Comment: Can you compare the project file before and after opening it on VS2012 to check for modifications?

Comment: there's an article about the deploy problem may be similar to this, please take a look at it and try to use VS 2012 Update 1 please: [reference](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747630/publish-not-working)

Comment: I'd make the move to VS2012 SP2 now..

Comment: I think creating a new publish profile can solve the problem, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite old. I propose installing not RC, but final VS and to the newest update - ms guys fixed a bunch of problems.