# Strange Web Deploy access issue

Tags: webdeploy

I'm getting an odd problem with connecting to a server.

The server's logs read:

```
2013-05-21 11:18:24 [IP ADDRESS] HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=[SITE NAME] 8172 administrator [MY IP] - 401 1 1326 214
```

I am using the administrator account so I can't understand why it's not allowing access!

I am using VS2012 and Web Deploy 3.0 on Server 2008R2 x86.

---

**UPDATE**

When using the command `msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisApp=<sitename>,username=administrator,password=<urpassword>,authtype=‌​basic,computername=https://<yourserver>:8172/msdeploy.axd?Site=<sitename> -authtype=basic` as suggested by @ShaikhOwais I get the following error:

> Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
>   More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("[COMPUTER NAME]") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.

- "Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password" - yep.
- "that the site you are connecting to exists" - yep
- "the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site" - it's the administrator...

Comment: what do you see when you run: msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisApp=<sitename>,username=administrator,password=<urpassword>,authtype=basic,computername=https://<yourserver>:8172/msdeploy.axd?Site=<sitename> -authtype=basic

Comment: @ShaikhOwais Hi, thanks for the reply - I updated the question with response.

Comment: have you tried qualifying the username with the domain?

Comment: @Maciej I qualified it with the domain as you suggested and now I get a 404... progression at least. Any ideas why MsDeploy.axd would be returning a 404? Services are turned on and Web Deploy is installed...

Comment: @Maciej Ah-ha! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479927/visual-studio-2012-web-deploy-to-windows-server-2008-r2-with-iis-7-and-msdeploy

Comment: @Maciej If you write your domain comment as an answer, I will mark as correct for a juicy bounty!

Comment: @dav_i: Glad to help. It seems that different things work for different people when it comes to msdeploy issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, you need to qualify the username with the domain to which your admin user belongs.

Your script should thus be:

```
 msdeploy.exe -verb:dump -source:iisApp=<sitename>,username=
<DOMAIN>\administrator,password=<urpassword>,authtype=‌​
basic,computername=https://<yourserver>:8172/msdeploy.axd?Site=<sitename> 
-authtype=basic
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen with me and it was share permissions issue that time

Can you try  "net use \server\c$\path\to\fodler" and see if you can access this directory?

If it does not help can you please reply - 
Are you getting first time this error ? was you able to web deploy on the same server earlier or you are doing first time with this server ?