# Deploying ASP.NET MVC application on Microsoft IIS server fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Hi I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application to the IIS server and I get the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (The account 'ASPNET' does not appear to
>   be valid. The account was obtained from this location:
>   'AspNetWorkerProcessIdentityName'.)

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Many thanks

Comment: Your server OS?WinServer 2003? Do you have an account 'ASPNET' on this server?

Comment: Im using WinServer 2008, i might not have ASPNET on the server....

Comment: Do you have the permission to create one ? or check this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ad736b21-e963-4cfd-98a4-916d98ccff58/aspnet-user-not-found-in-windows-2008-what-should-i-do-in-place-of-them

Comment: Where is the error actually coming from and how are you using web deploy?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone landed here recently trying to find a solution to this, try referencing this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946340/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-task-failed):

For me it was just a matter of closing Visual Studio and reopening it again.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a late answer, but just in case somebody encounter this. In my situation, just as Ryan mentioned I just had to close and open Visual Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating the Process Model Identity in the relevant Application Pool

Comment: Welcome on SO. Thanks for sharing. Can you give more details to your answers? You may want to take a look at [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).