# deploy asp.net web site on localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

Visual studio error, when i want to deploy web site on localhost:

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed. (The account 'ASPNET' does not
>   appear to be valid. The account was obtained from this location:
>   'AspNetWorkerProcessIdentityName'.)
>
> The account 'ASPNET' does not appear to be valid. The account was
>   obtained from this location: 'AspNetWorkerProcessIdentityName'. Some
>   or all identity references could not be
>   translated.       0   0   WebApplication3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check that the WMSvc Service (Web Management Service) set to 'Auto'

Also check this [FIX: ASP.NET does not work with the default ASPNET account on a domain controller](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315158)

and [Configure the Web Deployment Handler](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler)

Comment: @nocamer:- Check out this thread if it helps:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946340/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-task-failed Do let us know if that works!