# Web deploy results in Request too long only in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, webdeploy

Spent quite a bit of time configuring web deploy on IIS 7.5. I've made sure that Web Deploy 3.5 was installed with all features, and that both the Web Management Service and Web Deployment Agent is running.

In Visual Studio I'm able to use the publishing wizard and validate my connection to the server. Additionally I can click on 'preview' on the last step to see a list of files. If I choose only one to publish it kicks off the process like normal and then hangs.

```
Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection
problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.Learn more at: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)
```

Using Wireshark here's the end of the conversation once I started the deploy

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Request Too Long</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The request header length that was sent was 18,846 characters.

I've also been trying everything in here with no luck. [Visual Studio 2010 Web deployment task failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946340/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-task-failed)

Update:
Here's the beginning of the request that was sent:

```
OST /MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE HTTP/1.1
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1762.0
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: 5686a2d6-a28a-4a0e-80bb-3c3c92369c85
MSDeploy.sid: 414bbf3d-22d7-413f-b235-f28c01face66
User-Agent: Unknown;sid=414bbf3d-22d7-413f-b235-f28c01face66;op=Sync
MSDeploy.PassId: 1
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
MSDeploy.ProviderOptions: H4sIAAAAAAAEA....
```

Update 2:
Tried publishing in VS2013 and it worked like a charm..

Comment: I'm getting this error in VS2013!

Comment: I can't remember exactly what the cause was for this, but I can tell you that the error reporting for this tool is not very good. For your connection info `Server` is the fully qualified url, `Site Name` is the application name in IIS, `Destination URL` is simply what url you want to open up automatically in your browser once publishing has completed.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing the server to to https://myserver.com instead of http://myserver.com

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Where did you change that?