# Web Deploy (aka MsDeploy) returns ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED

Tags: visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am trying to execute from command line msdeploy like for example following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync 
        -source:package="Templates\TemplateAppPool.zip" 
        -dest:appPoolConfig="MyAppPool",computerName="...",userName="...",password="..." 
        -replace:objectName=processModel,targetAttributeName=idleTimeout,replace=00:45:00 
        -replace:objectName=add,targetAttributeName=managedPipelineMode,replace=Integrated 
        -allowUntrusted
```

And getting following error

```
Info: Using ID '0b2ec654-ae21-4848-897d-f644d95b4bfa' for connections 
to the remote server.
Error Code: ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED
More Information: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with 
the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server 
administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED
```

I've added -allowUntrusted to prevent possible errors with certificates on target machine. Because when I try to do it from VS 2013 it shows me error/warning about certificate on target machine. Anyway I am accepting wrong certificate and it goes further saying that it's all right with connection, but

when I try to publish from VS 2013 I am getting following

```
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to 
https://remotehost:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default%20Web%20Site ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4193,5): 
Error : Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. 
Known ProviderOptions are:skipInvalid.)
Publish failed to deploy.
```

Command itself is fine, because when I change target machine in command to local, it works.

Answer (score 14):

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and other local proxy-based software can interfere with the server connection. Try disabling or closing Fiddler and re-attempting the connection.
If Fiddler is not in use, [Microsoft's web-deploy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy) covers most other web deployment problems.

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Closed Fiddler and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.  The solution given here seems to work: [Web deploy results in Request too long only in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246783/web-deploy-results-in-request-too-long-only-in-vs2012)

A working solution was to use https instead of http to deploy.  This generates certificate warnings in my environment, but it at least lets me deploy.