# Lost the ability to deploy web from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015

Me and my colleague are developing an ASP.NET MVC application, which is deployed to the Microsoft Azure WebSites. For a long time, there were no problems with this. However, a few weeks ago, I lost the ability to deploy the web app. When trying to publish it via Visual Studio 2015, the IDE freezes for a while and then I get the error saying:

> Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)

When Googling the issue, people said it was caused by slow connection speed. This is not an option in our case, since my colleague is able to publish the web application with no problems. Does anybody know what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Check firewall settings!

Comment: Comparing our firewall settings, there were no explicit prohibitions in mine (or permissions in case of my colleague). I have also tried disabling my firewall completely, but still got the same problem when trying to publish.

Comment: Check these threads: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416074/msdeploy-error-connection-terminated-while-trying-to-deploy-website) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756339/web-deploy-aka-msdeploy-returns-error-connection-terminated)